# Conversion from JPG to PNG image without ImageIO.read()

Tags: java

I am trying to convert JPG image into PNG in Java 7. Suppose that [Image](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=19547371C4F3B839&id=19547371C4F3B839%21108&parId=19547371C4F3B839%21105&o=OneUp) is "damaged" because ImageIO.read() throws exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match
```

Therefore, it cannot be loaded this way. So I need load/read image without ImageIO.read()

My code:

```
public byte[] convertJpgToPng(byte[] originalPhotoData) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(originalPhotoData);
    
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(bais); //This line throws an exception, so I need to replace the ImageIO.read() method

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", baos);
    byte[] resultingBytes = baos.toByteArray();

    return resultingBytes;
}
```

It is possible to change the reading, or do I need to change my whole conversion method?

Comment: Or perhaps change your JPG: it looks corrupt.

Comment: Why would you imagine that you can 'sidestep' the fact that your image is corrupt by avoiding one particular API?

Comment: You would need to figure out exactly how your JPEG image is corrupt, and write specific pixel-oriented code to fix the corruption.  Or, you could just take the picture again.

Comment: @g00se because If I manualy transform this "corrupted" image from jpg into png, it can be loaded with ImageIO.read() without exceptions. But I need first to transform it from jpg to png.

Comment: Not sure how you're doing that. Your software opens the image then you save it as a png?

Comment: @g00se this method will be used to convert all "damaged" jpg/jpeg images which throws exception `Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match`. Then they can be loaded without an exception.

Comment: You didn't answer my question…

Comment: @g00se yes, first the image is opened/loaded and then is transformed/saved to png

Comment: ImageIO works with specific [`ImageReader`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html) with several hooks. You might find out how to detect and repair the data error and save a corrected raster. (=Your own child of the JPEG ImageReader).

Comment: Try im4java - it's a pure Java implementation of ImageMagick. Your test image opens fine for me in ImageMagick

Comment: Imagemagick definitely knows something is wrong though: *identify-im6.q16: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment `test-image.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/387*

Answer (score 0):

You can use external program like [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php), calling it from Java as described [here](https://dzone.com/articles/execute-shell-command-java).

In some cases external program may have better capabilities, maybe it is actually 16 bit JPEG XT, who may know.